# Rolling window with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to separate a dataset in the following fashion:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/curran/a08a1080b88344b0c8a7/raw/0e7a9b0a5d22642a06d3d5b9bcbad9890c8ee534/iris.csv")

sepal_length = df["sepal_length"]
sepal_length

0      5.1
1      4.9
2      4.7
3      4.6
4      5.0
      ... 
145    6.7
146    6.3
147    6.5
148    6.2
149    5.9
Name: sepal_length, Length: 150, dtype: float64
```

I would like to create another dataset, trying to predict those values, based in 10 previous observations for instance (Suppose that this dataset is ordered and date dependant).

So for my predictors, I would like to have another dataset having the 10 previous values for each index. this is:

```
10    x0 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9
11    x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10
...
```

where $ x_i $ is the sepal length at the i-th index.

Comment: Prediction based on last 10 values doesn't make sense particularly for iris dataset, all these samples are IID samples (at least in theory) and each sample is individually meant to predict corresponding target label. Am i missing something here?

Comment: I know, just imagine that is a timeseries. I just used it for showing a dataset. Bad election, tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
for i in range(1,11):
    df[f'feature_{i}']=df['sepal_length'].shift(i)
```